# Silverlight and skydrive/dropbox

Tags: silverlight, dropbox, onedrive

Can You read/write a file in your Skydrive with Silverlight?
Or if that isn't possible, can you dot it with Dropbox?

thanks,

Filip

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to download/upload files from/to DropBox if:

- your application is trusted OOB app
- or if you host your silverlight application on DropBox

Don't know about skydrive.
(you might want to look at this project http://sharpbox.codeplex.com/)

Comment: How can I "host your silverlight application on DropBox"

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to adapt this library for use with Silverlight. It's set up for Silverlight for WP7. http://cerulean.codeplex.com/documentation